# how to return null if picture box is null else return picture byte

Tags: c#

in my following code i want to return data the null if my PictureBox(pbspic) is null else if PictureBox(pbspic) contains a picture I want data to return picture byte so that I can save null or picture in my database

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pbspic.Image);
            bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Position = 0;
            byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            return data;
        }
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data;
dm2.ExecActQuery("StudentsInsert", cmd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try creating a metthod of your stream and then call it for picture like this

```
private byte[] GetPic(Image img)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pbspic.Image);
            bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Position = 0;
            byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            return data;
        }
    }
```

USAGE:

```
if (pbspic.Image == null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "NULL";
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.Image).Value = GetPic(pbspic.Image);
        }
        dm2.ExecActQuery("StudentsInsert", cmd);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like the following? :

```
else if(pbspic == null) /* Or it could be pbspic.Image == null, depends on which is null */ 
{
   ep.SetError(tbmonfee, "Image is missing.");
   return;
}
else
{
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pbspic.Image);
                bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                stream.Position = 0;
                byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

if(data == null) /* Or check data length if it's never null */ 
{
   ep.SetError(tbmonfee, "Image is missing.");
   return;
}
}
```

Comment: You can move this code to a new function and return values from there. Saying that, why do you want to return values from a button click event? You would probably want to set some message on your page. In any case, if you let me know what you want to do then I can help you better :)

Comment: You mean you are trying to edit some value on button click event and want show a message to user if picture is empty ?

Comment: right beenish. i actually want to save the picture in the database if user has set the picture in the picture box. if user has not set any pic in picture box than i want to save null in my database as my image column in database also allows null values.

Comment: Can you add the code for your button event, so that I can advise you exactly what change to make ?

Comment: no sister in my btn save event im saving the students record like student name student's father name, student's class etc but im having problem in saving picture only that's why i have paste the concerning problem code only in my question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10184/discussion-between-kashif-and-beenish-khan)

Comment: Kashif, I won't be able to join chat due to network restrictions. If you can put the code here then I will be happy to help :)